# Change Dock Expose Activation Time

Tags: snow-leopard, dock, expose

Is there a way to change the amount of time you have to click and hold on a Dock icon to activate Dock Expose? or maybe tie the right click to activate it?

Comment: None of the tweaking applications (Onyx, Cocktail, etc.) have this preference, so assume it may be non-existant.

Comment: I'm surprised-Dock Exposé is relatively fast in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a setting for just clicking on the icon with the mouse other than a default for turning it off...

defaults write com.apple.dock show-expose-menus -boolean

You can change the behaviour of when you drag a file onto a dock icon though...

Go to Finder Preferences and at the bottom of the general tab there is "Spring-Loaded folders and windows"

You can dis/enable it and change the delay time.